# Django query - Retrieve objects that don't have other object pointing to them

Tags: python, django

I've got a model named String that looks something like this:

```
class String(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, default=get_english)
    original_string = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

The default language for the strings is English, then, in the same table on the database, I have the translated strings with different languages, each one pointing to the corresponding string in English through `original_string`.

What I need is to retrieve the strings in English that DON'T have associated strings in another language, i.e., that don't have a translation.

Right now I'm iterating over all string in English and appending the ones I need to a list, like:

```
translatable_strings = String.objects.filter(language__name="English")

strings = []

for string in translatable_strings:
    if not String.objects.filter(language=translator_lang,
                                 original_string=string).exists():
        strings.append(string)
```

But I think that's a pretty nasty piece of code. Isn't there a way to make this in a single query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First condition**: language is english

**Second condition**: not exists another string that references it.

```
String.objects.filter( language = 'english', 
                       string__original_string__isnull = True )
```

A [foreignkey backward reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1115053/842935) is needed.

Comment: "Foreignkey backward reference" sounds exactly like what I'm looking for. I'll try that now.

Comment: @Filly, perhaps it is enough with `string__isnull = True` try it and come back with news.

Comment: @danihp you said `English strings don't references another model, is the other languages who references english string. Is not?` If other language reference english string then it should have reference in original_string. How my query will fail?

Comment: Indeed, your answer was very helpful! What I forgot to say in my question was that I need to specify in what language the string in English has not an string pointing to it (i.e. the string has not a translation in X language), so I ended up writing the query like: `String.objects.filter(language__name="English").exclude(string__language=translator.language)` and it works amazingly. Thank you VERY much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String.objects.filter(language__name="English", original_string__isnull=True)
```

Comment: English strings don't references another model, is the other languages who references english string. Is not?

Comment: Wouldn't this retrieve all strings in English? All strings in English have original_string=null, because they don't have a default string to point to (they're the default). I need to retrieve strings in English that are not the original_string of another string in a given language.

Comment: @AamirAdnan I found danihp's solution to suit my problem, but your answer using Q objects was helpful for another piece of code I needed to write. Thank you very much!